# How to click radio button with capybara in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to select a radio button with capybara and it can't find the radio button.  Here is my rspec test, view and error.  Please note that I am using factories for user, skills, etc.

Rspec test

```
  scenario "user chooses a couple skills and moves on to bio" do
    user = create(:user)
    skill = create(:skill)
    skill_two = create(:skill)
    skill_three = create(:skill)
    sign_in(user)
    visit onboard_skills_path

    choose(skill.name)    
  end
```

View

```
  <%= form_for(:onboard_skill, url: onboard_skills_path) do |f| %>
    <ul>
    <% @skills.each do |skill| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag("skill_ids[]", skill.id, current_user.onboard_skill_ids.include?(skill.id)) %>
        <%= f.label(skill.name) %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= f.submit "Next >", class: "submit_skills" %>
  <% end %>
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Unable to find radio button "Development 1"
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using `choose` to test for a radio button but in your provided view code you have a `check_box_tag`. Try either changing `check_box_tag` to `radio_button_tag` or if you really want a check box, use `check` instead of `choose`.

Note that you can also select a radio button or check box by searching for the id using find. This helps when capybara does not find it by the label name. Try:

```
find(:css, "#skill_ids_[value='#{skill.id}']").set(true)
```